# How to cURL this HTML form?

Tags: curl

I am trying to automate the login process into my dome's WLAN. The login form looks like this:

```
<form method="post" action="https://10.70.70.70/user/user_login_auth.jsp">
    <input align="center" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" id="username"  maxLength="256" AUTOCOMPLETE=OFF />
    <input align="center" type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" id="password"  maxLength="64" AUTOCOMPLETE=OFF />
    <input type="hidden" name="email" id="email" />
    <input type="hidden" name="user" id="user" />
    <input type="hidden" name="ssid" id="ssid" />
    <input type="submit" class="submit" name="ok" value="Log In" />
</form>
```

I only have to enter my user name and password in the browser. Following is my initial try but it doesn't seem to work. Any tips will be appreciated.

```
curl -X POST -F 'username=test' -F 'password=test' -k https://10.70.70.70/user/user_login_auth.jsp
```

UPDATE: I added the minimal HTML form. Every time I try to curl the server just returns the login page back. I assume I have to include some header and will try to find out how a request must look like with Chrome requests monitoring.

Comment: The form data in the screenshot does not match the data in the curl command.

Comment: @Quentin, thank you. I fixed the form. Thought the parameters email, user, ssid would not be neccessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
curl -k -d 'username=test&password=test' -b /tmp/c -c /tmp/c https://10.70.70.70/user/user_login_auth.jsp
curl -k -b /tmp/c -c /tmp/c https://10.70.70.70/user
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your command but it didn't work. However I updated my question, could you take a another look at it, please? Thanks

Comment: Added session saving by cookies saving and there's now 2 cURL commands